# How to reload the WebMap in ArcGis Javascript on selection of drop down value

Tags: arcgis

I am new to ArcGIS Javascript Map development and I am facing an issue with WebMap. I am loading a webMap with one WebMap ID. It is loading properly on Map. I have a drop down HTML element on the Map. I have a requirement like, WebMap has to be reloaded with different WebMap ID on selection of drop down values i.e each and every value in drop down should be mapped to different WebMap ID. Can someone help me in reloading the WebMap on selection of drop down value.

Thanks and regards,
A. T. Joseph Kumar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to destory the map Object and then re-create it by using `esri/arcgis/utils`.

```
map.destroy();
arcgisUtils.createMap(webMapItemID, "ui-map").then(function(response){
     map = response.map;
});
```

**Update:**

The above code is for 3.x version. For 4.0 version, all you need to do is to create an new instance of the `WebMap` and update the view.

```
var webmap = new WebMap({
    portalItem: { id: webmapid }
});
view.map = webmap; //the view here is Mapview
```

Here is a working example. https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=webmap-switch

Comment: Hi Kambi, I am using MapView in my POC and it is available in 4.0. I am getting http://js.arcgis.com/4.0/esri/arcgis/utils.js not found issue when I try to use this code.

Comment: @Joseph Your question did not mention that, so I assumed it is 3.x. I have updated my answer for 4.0 as well.

Comment: Glad to help, set the answer as correct so it would be helpful for others.